# Issue in creating user by shell script in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to create a user via shell script but it is not running. Here is my script

> $(deluser $1) $(useradd -m $1)
>   $(passwd $1)

. is this correct??

Answer (score 0):

That was wrong.

```
deluser ${1}; useradd -m /home/${1} ${1}

passwd $1
```

There is website where you can check bash syntax [here](http://www.shellcheck.net).